# Request is resented when service worker is activated

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am using service worker in asp core for PWA.
but so confused me because when service worker is activated, *and I press F12 in browser for access the dev tools*, **request is resented**, no matter browser is in offline mode or online mode!!!!!!

this is my service worker:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var version = 'v1.0::NetworkFirst';
    var offlineUrl = "/Home/Offline";
    function updateStaticCache() {
        return caches.open(version)
            .then(function (cache) {
                return cache.addAll([
                    offlineUrl,
                    '/','/Home/Index','/Home/Contact','/Home/About'
                ]);
            });
    }
    function addToCache(request, response) {
        if (!response.ok)
            return;
        var copy = response.clone();
        caches.open(version)
            .then(function (cache) {
                cache.put(request, copy);
            });
    }
    self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
        event.waitUntil(updateStaticCache());
    });
    self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
        event.waitUntil(
            caches.keys()
                .then(function (keys) {
                    return Promise.all(keys
                        .filter(function (key) {
                            return key.indexOf(version) !== 0;
                        })
                        .map(function (key) {
                            return caches.delete(key);
                        })
                    );
                })
        );
    });
    self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
        var request = event.request;
        if (request.method !== 'GET') {
            event.respondWith(
                fetch(request)
                    .catch(function () {
                        return caches.match(offlineUrl);
                    })
            );
            return;
        }
        event.respondWith(
            fetch(request)
                .then(function (response) {
                    addToCache(request, response);
                    return response;
                })
                .catch(function () {
                    return caches.match(request)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            return response || caches.match(offlineUrl);
                        })
                        .catch(function () {                           
                        });
                })
        );
    });
})();
```

I think there is something wrong in **addToCache function** maybe because I clone the request.

Comment: do you by chance have update on reload checked in the dev tools?

Comment: no, when  switched between offline & online mode